# Assigning static public IPs to Proxmox KVM guests

Tags: networking, kvm, proxmox

I'm currently using 5 public IPV4 addresses on a physical machine running Ubuntu Server, which I intend to replace with new hardware running Proxmox.

I'll do a P2V of the current Ubuntu install into a VM on the new one. I'll then need to replicate the networking on that guest, which currently looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
            address xx.xx.40.154
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            network xx.xx.40.0
            broadcast xx.xx.40.255
            gateway xx.xx.40.1

    auto eth0:0
    iface eth0:0 inet static
            address xx.xx.40.155
            netmask 255.255.255.0

    auto eth0:1
    iface eth0:1 inet static
            address xx.xx.40.156
            netmask 255.255.255.0
```

How should I configure things to work so that the VM is visible on its public IP addresses as it was then it was on the physical machine?

Right now, the default networking interfaces on the Proxmox host look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.10.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.10.1
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

I get the feeling that's not going to work though, but for some reason I can't find any guides to this. I'm not using a firewall or any other complications here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question got me a "Tumbleweed" badge - I thought I'd step in.

It transpires that yes, the above config will work. I was able to leave the data centre in a state of calm having installed the new machine.